# Alleged temperature dependance of activation energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

According to Master Organic Chemistry (https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/09/10/elimination-reactions-are-favored-by-heat/), in point number four, the activation energy for a reaction is temperature dependant ("So you can see by analyzing this term that activation energy can change with temperature!"). This is in contradiction with what multiple threads on here on this topic have claimed. Could someone clarify this confusion.

Comment: The original Arrhenius model considers Ea independent on T. But later, more sophisticated models consider its T dependence, involving thermal energy of molecules. //  So what is stated depends on the implicit context.